# AWS Lambda does not choose warm environments

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a script to keep two AWS Lambda functions warm:

```py
PING_DELAY = 300
last_ping = -PING_DELAY
while True:
    try:
        timer = Timer()
        timestamp_str = \
            datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
        print(f"Ping at {timestamp_str} ", end='', flush=True)
        response = lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName='myfunc',
            InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
            Payload=json.dumps({'command': 'ping'}))
        payload = json.load(response['Payload'])
        if 'errorMessage' in payload:
            raise Exception(payload['errorMessage'])
        else:
            my_time = timer.stop()
            stats = payload['stats']
            print(f"took {my_time}ms.   n_cold: {stats['n_cold']}   total_init: {stats['total_init']}ms", flush=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"AWS Lambda submit failed: {e}", flush=True)
    
    time.sleep(PING_DELAY)
```

Every five minutes, it invokes the `myfunc` AWS Lambda function, which in turn invokes in parallel 109 instances of another Lambda function. Based on the responses, `myfunc` reports in its response how many instances experienced a cold start (`n_cold`) among other measurements. Here is part of the output of this script:

```
Ping at 28.11.2023 08:58:06.605 took 586ms.   n_cold: 0   total_init: 0ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:03:07.291 took 7133ms.   n_cold: 4   total_init: 24215ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:08:14.524 took 54809ms.   n_cold: 0   total_init: 0ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:14:09.433 took 10211ms.   n_cold: 13   total_init: 77080ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:19:19.744 took 694ms.   n_cold: 19   total_init: 118006ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:24:20.538 took 4617ms.   n_cold: 0   total_init: 0ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:29:25.185 took 2042ms.   n_cold: 0   total_init: 0ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:34:27.327 took 566ms.   n_cold: 4   total_init: 24450ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:39:27.993 took 602ms.   n_cold: 8   total_init: 47270ms
Ping at 28.11.2023 09:44:28.695 took 658ms.   n_cold: 11   total_init: 66350ms
```

As the output shows, at least 90 of the 109 environments remain warm at all times. For the actual computation that I am interested in, `myfunc` invokes in parallel 50 instances of that same Lambda function. Given the availability of at least 90 warm environments, I would expect that all the 50 instances would be run in warm environments. However, the logs show that some of those 50 invocations result in a cold start. I checked that the computation did not coincide in time with the invocations for keeping the environments warm.

Why does AWS Lambda not choose a warm environment when an abundant number of such environments is available?

P.S. The [question in re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU0g0RW81CQhCTyi6gpFGvWw/aws-lambda-does-not-choose-warm-environments)